# Dovecot migration from mbox to mdbox

Tags: email-server, dovecot, migration, mbox

I am doing a migration from mbox to mdbox on a new disk. From /mnt/mail/$user to /mnt/mail2/$user

Current mail_location = mbox:~/mail:INBOX=/mnt/mail/%u/mail/Inbox

The new mail_location = mdbox:/mnt/mail2/$user/mdbox

My main userdb is passwd, and i have an override for all the users with another userdb:

```
userdb {
  driver = passwd
  result_success = continue-ok
}

userdb {
  driver = passwd-file
  args = username_format=%u /etc/dovecot/passwd.override
  skip = notfound
}
```

First step, overriding mail_location for that user:

```
$user:::::::userdb_mail_location=/mnt/mail2/%u/mdbox
```

Starting migration:

```
doveadm sync -f -u $user mbox:/mnt/mail/$user/mail:INBOX=/mnt/mail/$user/mail/Inbox
```

Sync goes well, all the folders and mails are there in the mdbox location on /mnt/mail2/$user/mdbox.

The home directory of that user is then changed from /mnt/mail/$user to /mnt/mail2/$user, permissions are set.

/etc/passwd shows that home dir of the user is /mnt/mail2/$user.

/etc/dovecot/passwd.override has the new mdbox mail_location for that user.

Unfortunately, when new mail arrives, it still goes to the old mbox.

Postfix uses dovecot-lda as delivery agent:

mailbox_command = /usr/lib/dovecot/dovecot-lda -f "$SENDER" -a "$RECIPIENT"

Is it possible dovecot-lda doesn't understand the override? 
And why it still delivers to the old $HOME for that user, no matter that it was changed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that `dovecot-lda` does not do userdb lookups, and my overridden `mail_location` was not in effect. Mentioned in the [docs](https://wiki.dovecot.org/LDA/Postfix), and the answer is to add `-d "$USER"` to the parameters.

In postfix the configuration for `mailbox_command` should be:

`mailbox_command = /usr/lib/dovecot/dovecot-lda -d "$USER" -f "$SENDER" -a "$RECIPIENT"`

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked into https://wiki2.dovecot.org/Migration/MailFormat? This is usually very easy to do with dsync using the instructions there.